# Show div only if content is found from database

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to show surrounding HTML only when content is available.

For example, the following HTML would only be rendered if `user_data.x` or `user_data.y` has a value:

```html
<div class="toggle toggle-primary" data-plugin-toggle="">
    <section class="toggle blue">
        <label>User data</label>
        <div class="toggle-content">
            <table>
                {% if user_data.x %}<tr>
                    <th>Data x</th>
                    <td>{{ user_data.x }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tr>{% endif %}
                {% if user_data.y %}<tr>
                    <th>Data y</th>
                    <td>{{ user_data.y }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tr>{% endif %}
            </table>
        </div>
     </section>
</div>
```

What would be the most convenient way to do this with Django?

I'm displaying partial data from multiple database tables. Therefore, making a big `if` over the whole HTML doesn't follow DRY.

Using a custom tag to test availability and render the content would solve the problem. However, I find this solution alarming since it's difficult and scatters the HTML while this seems like a very common issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do something like this in your view

`user_data.all = [user_data.x, user_data.y, ...]`

`user_data.any = any(user_data.all)`

in the template

`{% if user_data.any %}
    {% for elem in user_data.all %}
        <tr>
            <th>{{ elem.title }}</th>
            <td>{{ elem.data }}</td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
{% endif %}`

obviously that will only work if each element has.title and .data - but you could add a property to each existing model to produce that data

Comment: I also have some HTML rows that consist multiple database items. I wrote a class to associate a title to the data in the view. It's pretty convenient, thanks!